# Modeling the Motion of a Particle where $ ||\vec{f_i}|| = \frac{k_i}{r_i^2} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

At the origin of an $n$-dimensional space, there exists a single free-moving particle ($\gamma$) with a known mass ($m$) and velocity ($\vec{v}$). There also exists $p$ number of fixed points with known positions. Each point exerts a force on and in the direction of $\gamma$.

$$ ||\vec{f_i}|| = \frac{k_i}{r_i^2} \tag{0} $$

$r_i$ is the distance between $\gamma$ and point$_i$, and $k_i$ is a proportionality constant.

I am trying to model $\gamma$'s position and velocity at any time, $t$. I have made a number of attempts at this problem; however, I am hindered by my somewhat limited mathematical vocabulary. Please, walk me through the steps of this problem, and be clear about your notation. Feel free to begin by solving the problem in its simplest form: where $n = 1$ and $p = 1$.

### Example: $n=1$, $p=1$

Here is an example of this problem in its simplest form, where $\gamma$ only moves through one dimension and the force vector is only defined by

$$ f(x) = \frac{k}{(x-x_1)} \tag{1} $$

$x_1$ is the constant position of a given point.

The following image is a graph of the $f(x)$ where $k=10$ and $x_1=-2$.

[image]

Obviously, acceleration is given by

$$ a(x) = \frac{k}{m(x-x_1)^2} \tag{2} $$

and velocity is given by

$$ v(x) = \int{a(x)}dt \tag{3} $$

I am going to stop here, because I am not sure I know how to integrate the above equation correctly. Can someone help?

Comment: You are essentially describing a gravitational system of $p+1$ particles. Well, this seems the most natural description, but you have not specified what force each of the $p$ points exert on eachother besides $\gamma$. This is necessary information. However, if your setup is symmetric in the sense that $\gamma$ could be any of the particles, then you have described an $n$-body problem. You can solve explicitly perhaps with $n=1$ or $p=1$, but more dimensions require numerical simulations. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem

Comment: @nullUser I'm glad you brought up a gravitational system. Actually, what I had in mind was an electrostatic system. The two are essentially the same, except that electrostatic force can be positive or negative. The points are all fixed in place, so any force that they exert on each other is irrelevant. As a matter of fact, I called them "points", because they should not move or take up space. They only serve to define the electrostatic field through which $\gamma$ is moving. Keep in mind that $\gamma$ is the only moving particle in the system.

Comment: Convert it into a potential energy problem: i.e. each force is the gradient of the potential energy contribution of its point. You should be able to show that there is a "center of gravity" for the points such that your particle moves as if there were a single particle at that center.

Comment: @pseudoeuclidean An electrodynamic $n$-body problem is just as hard to solve as a gravitational one, namely you probably need to do it numerically. Also I should mention that by assuming the points don't move you are implicitly assuming they have infinite mass (or at least so large that your measurements cannot detect their movement). Though in this case of very large mass approximation, by following Paul's suggestion, you can always reduce to the $p=1$ case. I should mention that may not be a sensible model because if masses are very large, then gravity will be the dominant force, not charge.

Comment: ["Euler's three-body problem is to solve for the motion of a particle that is acted upon by the gravitational field of two other point masses that are fixed in space. This problem is exactly solvable" Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_three-body_problem)